# I am getting nova issue when i ran #nova image-list

Tags: linux, openstack

I am following the link http://openstins.tiddlyspot.com, everything goes smooth but when I ran below command I got error as below.

`[root@centos6-2 init.d]# nova image-list
ERROR: Not found (HTTP 404)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the nova client is not able to reach the auth server.

You need to supply your credentials as well as a target URL to the `nova` client. There are two ways you can do that:

### CLI options

You need to pass the following options to your command:

- `--os-username`
- `--os-password`
- `--os-tenant-name` (or `--os-tenant-id` if you prefer; you just need to specify a tenant)
- `--os-auth-url` (usually it's the address of your keystone server)

Here's what you should have:

```
nova --os-username=YOURUSERNAME --os-password=YOURPASSWORD --os-tenant-name=YOURTENANT --os-auth-url="https://KEYSTONE_URL/" image-list
```

### Environment Variables

Alternatively, you could set these variables in your shell's environment so you don't have to type them each and every time.

```
$ export OS_AUTH_URL=https://KEYSTONE_URL
$ export OS_TENANT_NAME=YOURTENANT
$ export OS_USERNAME=YOURUSERNAME
$ export OS_PASSWORD=YOURPASSWORD
$ nova image-list
```

Obviously you can set these variables in a file that you'd source every time you launch a shell, so it wouldn't get in the way.